# Get user detailed activity on Documents in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, versioning, audit

I currently have a client that needs to generate a report on the user's changes on the documents on every Document Library on every site collection.

I know I can use the [Audit module OOB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431342/Auditing-A-Built-in-Feature-of-SharePoint), but it doesn't show enough detailed data on the changes made on each item.

I was thinking about the detailed version history on the documents, but I would have to populate through every item of every list on every site collection. Something like [this](http://sptechnet.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/sharepoint-listitem-versioning-and-changes-in-c/).

I was thinking about doing a custom page that combines both. I can filter the audit info of a particular user on a particular date range, and use the ItemId to get it's versioning details up to the audit date.

What do you think? could that be possible? is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you **develop** a EventReceiver implemented in sitecollection level, so you can save "custom-made" any changes in elements of lists or libraries. So you can have your custom audit log in alternate database.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ec/library/ee231563.aspx

The EventReceiver is a good feature to keep high control in SharePoint Functionality.


Sorry for my bad english.